# Non-trivial problems about the trivial group

Tags: gr.group-theory, lo.logic, model-theory, universal-algebra

Is there any non-trivial problem (maybe open problem) about the trivial group?

I asked already a question about the [Laws characterizing the trivial group](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/252411/laws-characterizing-the-trivial-group). There is a description of such laws. As another example, one can ask about the first order sentences characterizing the trivial group. I am not sure if these sort of problems are trivial or easy. Is there any important (open) question about the trivial group?

Comment: Google Andrews–Curtis conjecture

Comment: @ Ievgen Bondarenko, thank you, this is very good example. Would you please write it as an answer (with some more explanations)?

Comment: The first-order theory of the trivial group is, er, trivial. A group is trivial if and only if its first-order theory contains the sentence $\forall x,~x=1$.

Comment: @ HJRW, I didn't mean the first order theory. I meant the first order sentences which are true ONLY in the trivial group. The sentence $\forall x \ x=1$ is one example. Another example is $\forall\ x, y\ ( [x,y]=1\to x^3y^2=1)$. How can we characterize all these sentences?

Comment: ["Groups of order 1" by E. S. Rapaport](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1964-015-05/S0002-9939-1964-0167516-5/S0002-9939-1964-0167516-5.pdf)

Comment: It is undecidable of a finite presentation presents the trivial group

Comment: Determining whether something is the trivial group is **not** a problem about the trivial group.

Comment: @M.Shahryari -- apologies, I misunderstood your suggestion.  That's a very nice problem!  (Surely the set of those sentences is undecidable, but a proof isn't obvious to me.)  Perhaps you should post it as an answer to your question?

Comment: @HJRW You are welcome. In my opinion this question is really a non-trivial problem about the trivial group. I also feel that it should be undecidable. Some weaker problems may also be interesting, for example, determining the set of all quasi-identities true ONLY in the trivial group. I am not sure if I can answer my own question.

Answer (score 5):

Problem 1.12 of [[Unsolved Problems in Group Theory, The Kourovka Notebook, Novosibirsk, 2010]](https://arxiv.org/abs/1401.0300):

(W. Magnus) The problem of the isomorphism to the trivial group for all groups with $n$ generators and $n$ defining relations, where $n>2$.

Problem 1.13 of [[Unsolved Problems in Group Theory, The Kourovka Notebook, Novosibirsk, 2010]](https://arxiv.org/abs/1401.0300):

(J. Stallings). If a finitely presented group is trivial, is it always possible to replace one of the defining words by a primitive element without chaning the group?

The answer is no, not always (S. V. Ivanov, Invent. Math., 165, no. 3 (2006), 525-549.

Problem 2.80 of [1](https://arxiv.org/abs/1401.0300) Does every non-trivial group satisfying the normalizer condition contain a non-trivial abelian normal subgroup? (S.N.Chernikov)

One may propose Problem 2.80 as follows: Is the trivial group the only group
satisfying the normalizer condition and not containing a non-trivial abelian normal subgroup.

Comment: Problem 1.13 is a good example. As @YCor says above, questions about characterizations of the trivial group are *not* problems about the trivial group. For instance, one could phrase a famous question in geometric group theory as "Is the trivial group the only hyperbolic group without a non-trivial finite quotient?"  Similarly, Problems 1.12 and 2.80 are not problems about the trivial group.

Answer (score 3):

In [Group trisections and 4-smooth manifolds](https://arxiv.org/abs/1605.06731), the authors proved that the smooth 4-dimensional Poincaré conjecture is equivalent to the following (purely group theoretical) statement about the trivial group: Every $(3k, k)$–trisection of the trivial group is stably equivalent to the trivial trisection of the trivial group.